# Cutting POSIXlt types by hour in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following data

```
plt <- seq(as.POSIXlt("2010-01-01 01:20:30"), as.POSIXlt("2010-12-31 12:00:30"), 
           length.out = 10)
df <- data.frame(plt)

                   plt
1  2010-01-01 01:20:30
2  2010-02-10 13:11:36
3  2010-03-23 02:02:43
4  2010-05-02 13:53:50
5  2010-06-12 01:44:56
6  2010-07-22 13:36:03
7  2010-09-01 01:27:10
8  2010-10-11 13:18:16
9  2010-11-21 00:09:23
10 2010-12-31 12:00:30
```

What I am trying to do is cut the following date by time. What I mean is I want to assign an A factor for times between 00:00:00 - 06:00:00, B factor to 06:00:01 - 12:00:00, C factor to 12:00:01 - 18:00:00,D factor to 18:00:01 - 24:00:00. Hoping for the factors to be found in a separate column in `df`. Anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: Hi, just curious how you have both 00:00:00 and 24:00:00 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the POSXlt information to extract the hour and then use `cut()` to create your groupings

```
df$timeclass <- cut(as.POSIXlt(df$plt)$hour, 
    breaks=c(0,6,12,18,24), 
    labels=c("A","B","C","D"),
    include.lowest=T)
df
#                    plt timeclass
# 1  2010-01-01 01:20:30         A
# 2  2010-02-10 13:11:36         C
# 3  2010-03-23 02:02:43         A
# 4  2010-05-02 13:53:50         C
# 5  2010-06-12 01:44:56         A
# 6  2010-07-22 13:36:03         C
# 7  2010-09-01 01:27:10         A
# 8  2010-10-11 13:18:16         C
# 9  2010-11-21 00:09:23         A
# 10 2010-12-31 12:00:30         B
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df) # converts df to a data.table

## Broken down into steps
df[, plt_numb := as.numeric(plt)]
df[, groups   := ((plt_numb - 1) %% 86400) %/% 21600]
df[, group_factors := factor(groups, levels=0:3, labels=c("A", "B", "C", "D"))]
```

In one single step:

```
 df[, newCols := 
        factor({((as.numeric(plt) - 1) %% 86400) %/% 21600}
            , levels = 0:3
            , labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D")
     )]
```

Note that
* 86400 == 24hrs * 60mins * 60 seconds
* 21600 ==  6hrs * 60mins * 60 seconds
Thus, taking modulo 86400 produces just the time value; taking the remainder division 21600 groups the values into sets of 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lubridate` to make your life easier. There probably is a nicer way to do this, but I think this way is the easiest to read.

```
library(lubridate)
df$time_factor <- as.factor(sapply(df$plt, function(x) {
  date_x <- floor_date(x, "day")
  if(x < date_x + hours(6)){ # time is 6am
    return("A")
  }
  if(x < date_x + hours(12)){ # time is midday
    return("B")
  }
  if(x < date_x + hours(18)){ # time is 6pm
    return("C")
  }
  if(x < date_x + hours(24)){
    return("D")
  }
}))
```